# Flying bug digging into my cats skin

Tags: bug-identification, ticks

I went outside one time and found my cat under my neighbors boat and there was a hole in her side with a black bug that looks like a tick and can fly it is round as well and I pet her but she turned around and I saw the tick and the hole in her and she nicked off the bug and ran away could anyone tell me what type of bug it is I live in Florida and she likes going into forests and eating bugs if that tells anything worth noting.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about this site and the sort of questions and answers we work with. Unfortunately, without pictures and a clear description, we aren't likely to be able to answer this question as it could be any one of thousands of species. Some more details *may* help. What size is the hole? Is there anything in the hole (e.g. botfly larvae)? Was the bug attached (like a tick) or just sitting there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's an [SE Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com) that might be better if your motivation is about how to help your cat rather than just a "what bug is it?" Q.